# How to make action link created by razor make POST?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I use mvc 5 in my project.

I create action link using razor that sent some data to action method by GET mthod.

Here is action link:

```
<tbody>
    @foreach (var item in Model)
         {
               <tr><td>@Html.ActionLink(item.Name, "About", "Home", item, new { @class = "btn btn-featured btn-white height-30 width-100" })</td></tr>
         }
 </tbody>
```

My question is how to change created action link above to make it sent data by POST to action method?

Comment: `ActionLink` helper always use `GET` because it generates anchor tag. If you want to perform POST request, use `jQuery.ajax()` or normal form submit instead.

Comment: A link makes a GET. If you want a POST, then use a form and submit it

Comment: Or you can handle the `click` event and use `fetch` or `$.ajax()` in the event handler to make a POST request

Answer (score 1):

You are using an HTML Anchor Link, which always do a GET action from Browser.

If your requirement is to do a post, you can use one of the below approaches:

**1. Ajax Post**

```
@Ajax.ActionLink("About", "Home", new { id = "myForm", @class = "btn btn-featured btn-white" }, new AjaxOptions { HttpMethod = "POST" })
```

For using @Ajax you will need to add a nuget reference from:
https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.jQuery.Unobtrusive.Ajax/

This will add new scripts to your project (jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js)

Without this, it will continue to use GET as your Method.

**2. Form Submit Post**

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("About", "Home", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "myForm", @class = "btn btn-featured btn-white" }))
{
   <a href="javascript:document.getElementById('myForm').submit()">
      <span>Submit</span>
   </a>
}
```

Comment: I tried it:

@Ajax.ActionLink(item.Name, "About", "Home", item, new AjaxOptions { HttpMethod = "POST" }, new { @class = "btn btn-featured btn-white height-30 width-100" })

But when I look at fiddler it shows GET request

Comment: And where do I put foreach?

Comment: @Michael assuming i have understood correctly, inside the `using`, and the `<a></a>` will go inside the `foreach`

Comment: Note about `@Ajax.ActionLink` helper: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22420512/ajax-actionlink-is-using-get-instead-of-post. Also it may necessary to use `preventDefault()` before using `submit()` function.

Comment: @Michael - I have updated the answer. Please add reference to nuget package https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.jQuery.Unobtrusive.Ajax/

Comment: Habeeb, thanks for post.In your example Form Submit Post how do I POST object to action method? in my case the object is item